# Convert Spark DataFrame to LabeledPoint for Naive Bayes

Tags: python, dataframe, naivebayes

I'm trying to convert a DataFrame to a LabeledPoint to use it in a Naive Bayes classifier. This is my code:

```
# These are the two dataframes
train = to_spark_df("train.csv")
test = to_spark_df("test.csv")

# These are the labels of the six classes
labels = [i for i in train.columns if i not in ["id", "comment_text"]]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="comment_text", outputCol="words")
wordsData = tokenizer.transform(train)

word2vec = Word2Vec(inputCol = "words", outputCol = "rawFeatures")
model = word2vec.fit(wordsData)
result = model.transform(wordsData) # This is the feature vector extracted with Word2Vec
```

At this point, I would like to create a LabeledPoint object with "labels" as first field which contains the classes of my dataset and "result" as second field which contains the features. I tried to map it but I couldn't. Can anyone help me?